# Unity error prepare 3 VideoPlayer 4K

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video

There is no problem to `Prepare` one or two (4K) `VideoPlayer` for Android (Samsung Galaxy S7).

But When I try to `Prepare` three or more (4k) `VideoPlayer` I get an error `AndroidVideoMedia: Error -10000 while configuring codec.` and the video doesn't play at all.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware **cannot** handle this not to mention that it is 4K which makes it even more likely to be the issue.

This is how to do this:

- Prepare video 1 only.
- Play video 1 and use coroutine to wait until video 1 has reahed half
  way, This can be determined with `VideoPlayer.clip.length / 2`.
- If video 1 has played *half way*, start preparing video 2 while video
  1 is still playing.
- When video 1 is done playing, destroy video 1 and start playing
  video 2.
- Repeat!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I already use this solution.
But there is two problems for my use.

- I have to play the first video in a loop. But the isLooping option doesn't loop well with 4K video. So I already use your solution to play the loop (2 videos players, wait half to prepare, ...).

- I have to play another video when the user clic. So I need another VideoPlayer to be ready. It work on a Galaxy S8, but not on a Galaxy S7.

Comment: You said the problem appear when preparing three or more. You can prepare 2 videos only then the third one only if the user clicks next while playing the first one. You should then be playing the second video which is already loaded.